# Keep unique ranked values from 2 character vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, comparison, character

I have two character vectors of length 5:

```r
x <- c("B","A","D","K","F")
y <- c("A","C","D","F","E")
```

The characteristics of these vectors are the following:

1. Each vector is ordered (for example, in vector `x` element `"B"` is more important than `"A"`)
2. There are no duplicates inside each vector, but there **may** be duplicates amongst them (as it's the case in this example)

What I want is to "merge"  these 2 vectors in order to obtain a new vector `z` **of length 5** which contains the most important **non duplicate** elements of vectors `x` and `y`, respectively, giving a priority to `x` in case of ties.
To be clearer, the logic of my program should work as follows:

1. Take the first element of `x` and `y`: if they're different, put them inside `z`
2. Take the second element of `x` and `y`: if there's a value that is already inside `z`, ignore it. Else, put it in.
   Another way to see this is: if there's a value which is stored in an higher position either in `x` or `y`, ignore it. Else, put it inside `z`.
3. Go to the next position and perform 2 again, comparing each value to all the values in higher positions both in `x` and `y`.
4. Stop when `length(z)==5`

In my example it would work as follows:

1. Put `B` and `A` inside `z`
2. Put `C` inside `z`
3. Put `D` inside `z` (which is now of length 4)
4. We have now values `K` and `F`: if we put both, `length(z)` will be 6, so take just `K` as it's inside `x` (priority)

The resulting vector would be `z = c("B","A","C","D","K")`.

I could transform the vectors in lists or whatever, but I would like to avoid using loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
x <- c("B","A","D","K","F")
y <- c("A","C","D","F","E")
df=(t(data.frame(x,y)))
(result=unique(as.vector(df))[1:5])
[1] "B" "A" "C" "D" "K"
```

Thanks for nice detailed explanation.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for: easy and clean. Nice move with the `as.vector` part: I didn't think of that way to concatenate the vectors keeping the order of their elements :)